# Facebook App request in iOS (not using Dialog)

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I need to send a request throw my app to user's friends in Facebook (After the app on Facebook is authorized) I know there is a way to do it through the SDK :

```
[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:nil];
```

But I don't need that way to show the dialog I just need to be able to send the request in the background when the user select the friend from (Table View for example).

Is this possible?

Comment: WHat request you want to send in background ? You have not mentioned.

Comment: oh sorry ,,, a request to a friend to play a game. like in the default Facebook apprequests dialog

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Dialog API has not been updated (yet, hopefully). You can't bypass the dialog the way you want to do it.
But, you can :

1. preselect the friends with your own GUI and gives the apprequest the selected facebook ids. This way, the dialog is just to confirm the request.
2. activate the frictionless parameter, to avoid the dialog the next time you send the request for the same selected friends (the confirm dialog seems to show anyway, though, and immediately disappear, it gives a not-so-nice blink on the screen).

here's the related documentation, in case you need it : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: How do you manage to get the user just to click "Send" on the FB's dialog? I always get this dialog:
https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/ios_requests_device_filtered_off.png
and the user will need to select the friend from the friend list again... :(

Comment: If I'm only to send to a single friend, I can achieve that, but I need to send multiple requests at once...

Comment: 1. enable frictionless on your Facebook* object : `[self.facebook enableFrictionlessRequests];` 2. define list of string facebookIds of your recepients; put this list in a dictionary using the key "to"; 3. give this dictionary (containing all the other values you need for your dialog) to the dialog method : `[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];` 4. vote for this answer if that does work you u :)